# Ist die Redewendung "das mache ich mit links" diskriminierend?

Tags: phrase, proverb

Neulich sagte ich angesichts der recht übersichtlichen Menge an Arbeit zu meinem Kollegen:

> "Ach, das machen wir doch mit links."

Worauf dieser, ein Linkshänder, halb scherzhaft meinte, dass man das so nicht sagen könne.

Nun frage ich mich, ob diese Redewendung tatsächlich einen Linkshänder diskriminiert; oder anders gefragt, ob denn auch ein Linkshänder diese Wendung so gebrauchen würde.

Comment: Ersatzvorschlag: „Ach, das schaffen wir doch mit der nichtdominanten Körperseite!“ :-)

Comment: @chirlu Oups, ich schreibe mit rechts, aber springe mit links. Was ist jetzt meine "nichtdominante Körperseite"?

Comment: @Em1, Ersatzersatzvorschlag: „Ach, das schaffen wir doch mit der für diese Aufgabe nichtdominanten Körperseite!“ ;)

Comment: Die Frage führt in die Irre! Die Überschrift redet von der ersten Person singular, also in Deinem Fall womöglich von einem Rechtshänder, der die Aufgabe eben auch mit links erledigen könnte. Die Frage nach Ungleichbehandlung kommt hier gar nicht in Betracht, da Du ja nur das eine oder das andere sein kannst. Ein "Wir" dagegen, das einen Linkshänder mit unter die subsummiert, für die ... usw., das ändert die Situation, und macht die Frage überhaupt erst möglich.

Comment: Ersatzvorschlag: „Ach, das schaffen wir doch mit der Körperseite, die weniger auf diese Aufgabe trainiert wurde.“ (Der Ursprung der Sinistralität ist unklar.)

Comment: Beachte: Webdesigner erledigen das meiste ihrer Arbeit mit Links :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Anbetracht dessen, dass diese Redewendung aus der überdurchschnittlichen Ausprägung von Rechtshändern in der Bevölkerung entstand, kann man durchaus sagen, dass empfindliche Geister diese als diskriminierend betrachten könnten.

Dazu kann man jedoch sagen, dass die Redewendung so geläufig ist und (zumindest in Süddeutschland) so häufig verwendet wird, dass schon ein ausgeprägter Konfliktwunsch notwendig ist, um daraus eine Diskriminierung abzuleiten, bzw. einen Streit vom Zaun zu brechen.

**TL,DR:**
Nein, durchaus nicht. Es soll jedoch kleingeistige streitsuchende Menschen geben, die auch solche Dinge als Anlass nehmen.

Comment: Du behauptest damit, dass Diskriminierung ein Motiv vorraussetzt. Diskriminierung heißt aber nur "Ungleichbehandlung" - dass eine böse Absicht dahinter steckt; alleine schon dass eine Schlechterbehandlung vorliegt, ist aber gar nicht gesagt.

Comment: @userunknown mir war nicht klar, dass die absichtliche Ungleichbehandlung mit von vornherein definiertem Motiv der Selbsterhöhung und der Erniedrigung des Gegenübers ohne böse Absicht geschieht. Diskrimnierung setzt in meinem Verständnis eine solche böse Absicht voraus, alles andere ist "Ungleichbehandlung".

Comment: Diskriminierung ist lediglich der fremdsprachliche Begriff dafür. Er wird aber meistens für absichtsvolle Ungleichbehandlung und meistens für Schlechterbehandlung verwendet.

Answer (score 2):

Ich bin Linkshänder - ich sage das auch und fühle mich nicht diskriminiert dadurch. Ich will aber keinesfalls für die linkshändische Gesamtheit sprechen.

Ähnlich betrachten das übrigens viele Blinde: Man sagt unbedacht mal "Mensch, das müssen wir nochmal näher anschauen". Meist bekommt man dann eine ziemlich coole Antwort.

Comment: In einer Führerscheinprüfung anzukreuzen "Ich nehme Blickkontakt auf", wenn es darum geht, einen Blinden, der über die Strasse will, in einer 30er Zone herüberzulassen, ist allerdings hoffnungslos, da gibt es keine coolen Ausreden mehr..

Answer (score 1):

Nein, der Linkshänder hat nur einen Witz gemacht.

Comment: Etwas linkisch geraten, der Witz.

Answer (score 0):

Ich sehe darin absolut **keine Diskriminierung**, weil das eine vom Volk anerkannte Redewendung ist. Wenn jemand gerne beleidigte Leberwurst spielt, wird er sich angegriffen fühlen, aber gegen solche Leute kannst du eh nichts unternehmen, die finden **immer** was.

Wenn der andere eventuell tatsächlich **keine Hand** mehr besitzt, sollte man sowas eventuell lassen, aber selbst dann werden noch die meisten das nicht als Diskriminierung ansehen.

Ich geh mal stark davon aus, dass ebenfalls Linkshänder diese Redewendung benutzen, es geht ja darin nicht um den wortwörtlichen Sinn (Hab es auch schon von Linkshänder gehört).

Comment: Die Argumentation ist ganz schlecht, denn sie unterstellt, dass das Volk (ein Volk, jedes Volk?) keine Diskriminierende Redewendungen dulden würde. Das Volk möchte ich sehen!